# Create interface web for a jar file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a form of verification tools executable jar file, and want to create a web interface
how to start? how to use the functionality of the file? I have not an idea please help me

Comment: Create a webapplication which has the jar file in it's classpath.

Comment: for example, the idea is to browse a file from the interface and start checking (the need to call the jar file), the question is how to handle the event? how to call the file jar to check

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a beginner, I'd suggest looking at Grails and importing the library into a Grails project. Grails is based on Spring, Hibernate and JavaEE, but significantly easier to use than most frameworks since it's modeled on Ruby on Rails.